# I want to send data when I tap a button in tableView Cell

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am implementing a commentView for my app. I have a main view which is tableview contains picture and a button to go comment view.
I want that when user tap comment button in table view, view shows comment view and pass PFObject by prepareforSegue method.

now comment button works, but I have an error from prepareforsegue
here is my code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if (segue.identifier == "mainToComment") {


let destViewController : CommentVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentVC
destViewController.parentObjectID = parentObjectID
let selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

destViewController.object = (postsArray[(selectedRowIndex?.row)!] as? PFObject)
```

and here is my how my button works.

```
 @IBAction func commentButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let view = button.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! MainTVCE
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    parentObjectID = postsArray[(indexPath?.row)!].objectId!!
```

when I debug, selectedRowIndex has no value(nil)
I think it cause of I tap button instead of cell.

How can I set indexPath for this?
or 
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know name of your main TableViewCell view controller. Assume that, I name this view controller is `MainTableViewCell`.

I create a closure in `MainTableViewCell`:

```
var didRequestToShowComment:((cell:UITableViewCell) -> ())?
```

When button comment is tapped:

```
@IBAction func commentButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.didRequestToShowComment?(self) // self is this UITableViewCell
}
```

In `table cellForRowAtIndex...` of your main view controller.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    ...
    mainTableViewCell.didRequestToShowComment = { (cell) in
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let objectToSend = postsArray[indexPath.row] as? PFObject
        // Show your Comment view controller here, and set object to send here
    }
    ...


    return cell
}
```

Comment: // Show your Comment view controller here, and set object to send here
            self.objectTwo = objectToSend!
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToComment", sender: self)       I declare objectTwo above, is there better way to set object?

Comment: I usually present view controller by code behind, not show by `segue` defined in storyboard. let commectVC = ....; commentVC.data = objectToSend; self.presentViewController(commentVC, animated: true, completion: nil). This may not be the best way, but it can achieve your requirement.

Comment: I am trying to attach click event to images inside table view cells. Click even is generalized to take effect based on the cell which contains the image. Thanks. Your answer helped me indirectly.

Comment: It's cleaner if you use self.didRequestToShowComment?(self)

Comment: @LachezarTodorov Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my answer.